# How to extract a value from a command output in a shell script?

Tags: regex, shell

The Linux command is `sudo parted /dev/sda unit s print free | tail -2`.
In my case it returns something like this:

```
        34605056s  67108830s  32503775s  Free Space
```

I need to capture the first number string and the second number string.

The goal is to create a new partition fitting the remaining free space perfectly.

I tried to use grep, but the best I could achieve was just getting colored matched numbers, but they can't be used in script as parameters:

```
sudo parted /dev/sda unit s print free | tail -2 | grep -oP '(\d+s\b)'
```

gives

```
34605056s
67108830s
32503775s
```

I need something that would return exactly '34605056s' and '67108830s' that I would be able to put into `mkpart` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you please try:

```
read -r start end _ < <(sudo parted /dev/sda unit s print free | tail -2)
```

then you can pass the variables `$start` and `$end` to `mkpart`

Answer (score 2):

AWK comes in handy:

```
echo "        34605056s  67108830s  32503775s  Free Space" |
  awk '{print $1, $2}'
```

Output:

```
34605056s 67108830s
```